# echo statement appends string to beginning instead of end

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, echo, zsh

I am trying to append `/api/json` to a url and echo it in the terminal. However the output looks strange. I see the string i'm trying to append ends up at the start of first string, also removing `https://h` from the url. Why does this happen?

```
❯ echo $location
https://hyc-************devops.com/queue/item/126498/
❯ echo "$location"/api/json
/api/jsonyc-************devops.com/queue/item/126498/
```

proof :

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It is appended in both bash and zsh. Looks like you have `\r` symbol somewhere. Check the the assignment of  `location`.

Comment: location is assigned from an api response. how can i remove the \r if present?

Comment: Never mind. Heres the solution that worked :    echo ${location//[$'\t\r\n']}api/json